# Magento message "not mr ..?"

Tags: magento-1.9

We have just noticed yesterday that sometimes we see a "not ...." when you are logged into magento. This is different to the "welcome ..." you see when you are logged in. This "not ..." is a link and links to "/persistent/index/unsetCookie". When I click on this link it ends up taking me to my account page.

Why is this "not ...?" showing, what is it for and why has it only started appearing now? We are running on Magento 1.9.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows up if you enabled "Persistent Shopping Cart" and the logged in user used the "Remember me" checkbox when logging in. This feature sets a cookie that logs the user in when his session expired as long as the cookie is there.

And in case that another person uses the same computer, the link is shown to log out and delete the "remember me" cookie.